# Unable to install Intel HAXM for Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github, visual-studio-2019

Intel HAXM is a prerequisite for compiling Android Studio code. When I try to install it through the SDK manager, it downloads fine, but while installing, says:

> HAXM installation failed. To install HAXM follow the instructions found at: https://software.intel.com/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

So I did the same and downloaded the files from GitHub. I followed the instructions, but when I try to build the .sln file, there is another error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State

> Error  MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found. To build using the WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools, please install WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by selecting the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution".   haxm-core   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  390

Please guide me what I should do. I would be grateful if someone can compile the file for me....

Comment: install the [last version](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/latest) on your own

Comment: @magicandre1981 That's exactly what i did and got an error message in Visual, as mentioned above. I also tried retargeting the solution to version 10.0, as mentioned in the error message, but to no prevail.

Comment: You download the source, not the installer. Thge message means you haven not installed the Window 10 WDK to compile drivers.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks a lot, I had not tried to download from the link you posted. Downloading from there worked.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that [you can accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

> Error MSB8020 The build tools for WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0
>   (Platform Toolset = 'WindowsKernelModeDriver10.0') cannot be found.

means you have not installed the Windows 10 WDK. But you don't need to compile it on your own, simply install the [last version](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/latest) `haxm-windows_vVERSION.zip` .

You can also try [Hyper-V Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows#accelerating-android-emulators-on-windows) if you get HAXM issues.